# Javascript click not loading woocommerce checkout page

Tags: jquery, json, woocommerce, checkout

In the following code, my button click is functioning. The product is added to the cart. But I must do a manual reload of the page for the `woocommerce_checkout` to load on the page (same page).

I tried `location.reload` and I also tried to redirect to another page where I also have the `woocommerce_checkout` shortcode but nothing seems to work.
All help is appreciated.

```
    jQuery('#submitproject').on('click', function () {
    jQuery.post({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url',
        data: {
            action: 'wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status != 'success')
                alert(data.msg);

            else
            {

                var numeroproduit = idproduit;
                console.log(numeroproduit);//15
                jQuery.get('/?post_type=product&add-to-cart='+numeroproduit, function () {});
                console.log("produit rajout");
                // window.location.href = "/paiement-projet";
                // location.reload();
                jQuery('#monpaiement').show();
                //jQuery('#mesinfos').hide();
                //jQuery('#monprojet').hide();
                //jQuery("#monpaiement").slideToggle();
                //jQuery('#submitproject').toggleClass('opened closed');
                console.log("after click success");

            }
        }

    });
});
```

Modified code trying to use Axelle's solution :

```
    jQuery('#submitproject').on('click', function () {
    jQuery.post({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: ''
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status != 'success')
                alert(data.msg);

            else
            {

                var numeroproduit = idproduit;
                console.log(numeroproduit);//15
                jQuery.get('/?post_type=product&add-to-cart='+numeroproduit, function () {});
                console.log("produit rajout");
                //window.location.href = '/?post_type=product&add-to-cart'=+numeroproduit;
                // location.reload();
                window.location.reload(true);
                jQuery('#monpaiement').show();
                //jQuery('#mesinfos').hide();
                //jQuery('#monprojet').hide();
                //jQuery("#monpaiement").slideToggle();
                //jQuery('#submitproject').toggleClass('opened closed');
                console.log("after click success");

            }
        }

    });
});
```

As you can see I modified the url to not use the action hook and I added the page refresh javascript.

No the checkout does not appear. New code above. This code is included in a document.ready function. Correction, the new code doesn't work. It doesn't accept the url aadmin-ajax.php. Got a bad request alert. Sorry.

Comment: when you reload the page with location.reload, does the page actually reload or does nothing happen?
when you do a manual reload, does the checkout appear?

Comment: Yes the page does reload. I tried several locations but you can see where it is. 2 lines after the console.log

Comment: can you try window.location.reload(true); when you set it to 'true', it will reload a fresh copy from the server. when you leave it out it will serve the page from your cache.

Comment: location.reload(true); will work too.

Comment: Thanks. When I use window.location.reload(true) it empties the basket, even after I took away the hook ?action=wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url'. The console log messages are firing correctly and the submit button also correctly creates the form's function which is to create a post

Comment: and does the checkout appear?
could you post a plunkr of your current code?

Comment: No the checkout does not appear. New code above. This code is included in a document.ready function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203746/discussion-between-axelle-and-rich).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code that functions. Thanks for the help.

```
jQuery('#submitproject').on('click', function () {
    jQuery.post({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url',
        data: {
            action: 'wc_woocommerce_clear_cart_url'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.status != 'success')
                alert(data.msg);

            else
            {

                var numeroproduit = idproduit;
                console.log(numeroproduit);//15
                jQuery.get('/?post_type=product&add-to-cart='+numeroproduit, function () {});
                console.log("produit rajout");
                window.location.href = '/?post_type=product&add-to-cart='+numeroproduit;
                jQuery('#monpaiement').show();
                jQuery('#mesinfos').hide();
                jQuery('#monprojet').hide();
                jQuery("#monpaiement").slideToggle();
                jQuery('#submitproject').toggleClass('opened closed');
                console.log("after click success");

            }
        }

    });
});
```

As you can see I do a window.location.href to the get url and this sends me to the checkout page without refreshing and the item is in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

This page maynot able to load woocommerce checkout scripts,

In this two way you can add the script to enable js events on your custom checkout page

1. add `wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-checkout' );` or
2. Add `add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_checkout', '__return_true')`